# Android : Issues with medialets ads

Tags: android, ads

I wanna use medialets ad in my android app. I have faced some issues which are listed below,

1. Got an sample with downloaded sdk, banner ads are not working in the sample itself, can anyone got this issue, whats wrong with the banner ads?
2. And Interstitial ads are working fine with the normal activity which extends AdActivity. If I load the following lines in oncreate then its getting crashed.

   ```
   InterstitialAdView view = new InterstitialAdView(AdDemo.this);
   view.setSlotName("ViewTwoFull");
   view.prepare();
   ```

   If I give that inside onclick() then its working fine.
3. Actually I want to load the interstitial ads when an item clicked in the list, my list activity is there with in the tab activity, in this case interstitial ad also not coming.

Can anyone worked with medialets, how to solve these issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am the Lead Integration Engineer at Medialets. Please email help@medialets.com with the name of the App you are working on, the SDK version, and the issues you are having. We will get back to you with help as soon as possible.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply, I have already mailed to help@medialets.com. Have you tried loading the ads on activity which is under tab activity? are you getting banner ads in the sample?

Answer (score 0):

@ Ashok : uset these two lines in ur oncreate method

```
getAdManager().setServiceListener(this);
getAdManager().start(getParent());
```